# How can i add the sub collection in a data model? flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, datamodel

how can i get the list products in my sub collection and add it to the data model i created.
I am trying to get all the products added to cart from a vendor..
here is the structure of my database
[image]

and here is the data code i am trying to do

```
class cartModel {
      vendorCartModel? vendorCart;
      List<productCartModel>? productsInCart;
    
      cartModel();
    
      cartModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snap){
        vendorCart = vendorCartModel.fromSnapShot(snap);
        productsInCart = ?????? (here is the part where i don't know what to do')
      }
      }
================

class vendorCartModel {
  bool selected = false;
  String? storeName;
  String? uid;
  String? userId;
  String? vendorToken;
  GeoPoint? storeLocation;

  vendorCartModel();
  vendorCartModel.fromSnapShot(DocumentSnapshot snap){
    storeName = snap["storeName"];
    uid = snap["uid"];
    userId = snap["userId"];
    vendorToken = snap["vendorToken"];
    storeLocation = snap["storeLocation"];
  }
}
==========================

class productCartModel {
  bool selected = false;
  String? name;
  List<dynamic>? imgUrl;
  String? uid;
  String? vendorUid;
  int? quantity;
  double? sellingPrice;
  double? sellerPrice;
  double? oldPrice;
  double? weight;
  bool? shipping;
  int? minOrder;
  
  productCartModel();

  productCartModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snap){
    uid = snap["uid"];
    vendorUid = snap["vendorUid"];
    imgUrl = snap["imgUrl"];
    name = snap["name"];
    weight = snap["weight"];
    sellingPrice = double.parse(snap["sellingPrice"].toString());
    sellerPrice = double.parse(snap["sellerPrice"].toString());
    oldPrice = double.parse(snap["oldPrice"].toString());
    quantity = snap["quantity"];
    minOrder = snap["minOrder"];
    shipping = snap["shipping"];
  }
}
```

================
here is my structure of database

- cart (collection)

  - fields (this will be used as vendor)

    - products ( sub collection )

==============
this is my query

```
await _fStoreIns
            .collection('cart')
            .doc(vendorId).get().then((value){
cartModel = cartModel.fromSnapshot(value);
})
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we get the vendor's data and then the productsData and pass both to `cartModel.fromSnapShot` method.

Use this query:

```
DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> vendorData =
    await _fStoreIns.collection('cart').doc(vendorId).get();
QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> productsData = await _fStoreIns
    .collection('cart')
    .doc(vendorId)
    .collection('products')
    .get();
cartModel = cartModel.fromSnapshot(vendorData, productsData);
```

Define your `cartModel.fromSnapshot` as below:

```
cartModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot vendorData, QuerySnapshot productsData) {
  vendorCart = vendorCartModel.fromSnapShot(vendorData);
  productsInCart = productsData.docs
      .map((e) => productCartModel.fromSnapShot(e)).toList();
}
```

Comment: wow thank you so much..it works..with a few modifications it works great..
i have just fixed the productsInCart query into this ..
productsInCart = productsSnap.docs
      .map((e) => productCartModel.fromSnapShot(e)).toList();

Comment: So glad I could help. I have corrected the error. You can upvote my answer to make it easier to find.

Answer (score 0):

> For Updating data

```
final pushData = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('cart');
pushData
        .doc(cardId)
        .collection("products")
        .doc(productId)
        .set({
         changes:"Changes"
         })
```

> For adding data

```
final pushData = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('cart');
pushData
        .doc(cardId)
        .collection("products")
        .add({
          data: "DATA"
        });
```

> For getting data

```
await pushData
        .doc(productid)
        .collection("products")
        .orderBy("timeStamp", descending: true) // if you want to order by time or whatever
        .limit(50) //for adding limit add limit
        .get();
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understood correctly you have the following structure in fbCloudStore

```
-vendors (collection)
 -vendor (doc)
  -products (colecction)
   -product (doc)
```

To get the specific subcollection you can do:

```
final vendorId = 'Replace with vendor Id';
    final _querySnapshot = await _fStoreIns
            .collection('vendors')
            .doc(vendorId)
            .collection('products')
            .get();
    
    
    for(final doc in _querySnapshot.docs){
      //do stuff here
      ProductModel.fromJson(doc.data());
    }
```

Comment: my structure is like this
- cart (collection)
  - fields (this will be used as vendor)
    - products ( sub collection )

what i wanted to get is something like this
 await _fStoreIns
            .collection('cart')
            .doc(vendorId).get().then((value){
cartModel = cartModel.fromSnapshot(value);
})

where in inside my cartModel.fromSnapshot is

cartModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snap){
    vendorCart = vendorCartModel.fromSnapShot(snap);
    productCart.add(ChkOutItemModel.fromSnapshot(snap['subCollection of products']));
  }

Answer (score 0):

my structure is like this

```
- cart (collection)
  - fields (this will be used as vendor)
    - products ( sub collection )
```

what i wanted to get is something like this

```
await _fStoreIns
            .collection('cart')
            .doc(vendorId).get().then((value){
cartModel = cartModel.fromSnapshot(value);
})
```

where in inside my cartModel.fromSnapshot is

```
cartModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snap){
    vendorCart = vendorCartModel.fromSnapShot(snap);
    productCart.add(ChkOutItemModel.fromSnapshot(snap));
  }
```

Comment: This appears to be supporting information to the question. Rather then post it as an answer you can edit the original question with the information